# How do I fill this vector?  Stroustrup example

Tags: c++, loops, vector

I am reading Stroustrup's Programming Principles and Practice Using C++.  On page 287 he gives an example under the heading of Order of Evaluation.  But I do not completely understand the example.  As constructed, "stringy" inputs will be created and destroyed every time until someone types "quit".

How would I change the code so that vector v contains every string inputted?  As written, I think v.size() would never be more than 1.  I want it to iterate through a loop and insert everything looped over into the vector rather than insert, delete and insert as it loops.

(code from book)

```
vector <string> v; //this is defined globally

void function()
{

     string s;
     while(cin>>s && s!="quit")
     {
     string stripped;
     string non_letters;

     for (int i=0; i<s.size(); ++i)
         if (isalpha(s[i])) 
              stripped +=i;
         else 
              not_letters += s[i];
     v.push_back(stripped);
     }

}
```

Comment: Please post real code. What you posted is a mess that makes no sense.

Comment: @Jerry Carson: It's not a violation of copyright if the code snippets are "*for purposes such as criticism, comment, news reporting, teaching (including multiple copies for classroom use), scholarship, or research*" according to [fair use](http://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/17/107.html). Surely this question falls under either "scholarship" or "research", or perhaps even "teaching" since that's really the whole point of this site. We need to see at least your actual code snippet in order to help you.

Comment: *for copyright reasons, this code is not exactly the same as the code from the book* Won't do sir, please post the code in book or atleast a free standing minimalistic example of it.

Comment: Can you please be more clearer with your question? At this point, I *think* you're trying to say "I want to try and make a program that reads in a bunch of inputted strings and stores them in vector `v1`". Unfortunately, you're a little unclear at the moment so a bit of clarification here would be really helpful ^^ Also, welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 0):

For every inputted `s` the for loop fills `stripped` with the letters of s. Then before the end of the while loop it is pushed at the end of `v1`. So `v1.size()` is the number of non-quit inputs.

Mind, `push_back` does a string copy, and at `}` the destructor of `stripped` is called. (In fact the compiler will optimize these two operations away.)